# How to drag element in specific location using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-draggable

jquery code

```
 $("#products li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});
$(".shoppingCart ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var self = $(this);
        self.find(".placeholder").remove();
        var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
        if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length) return;
        $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "data-id": productid
        }).appendTo(this);
        // To remove item from other shopping chart do this
        var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('id');
        $(".shoppingCart:not(#"+cartid+") [data-id="+productid+"]").remove();
    }
}).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
    sort: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
});
```

and this is html code

```
<div id="products">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Blocks</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ul>
            <li data-id="1"> 10000$ </li>
            <li data-id="2"> -10000$ </li>
            <li data-id="3"> 10000$ </li>
            <li data-id="4"> -10000$ </li>
            <li data-id="5"> Bank </li>
            <li data-id="6"> Loan </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="shoppingCart1" class="shoppingCart">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Cresit Side</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol>
            <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="shoppingCart2" class="shoppingCart">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Debit side</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol>
            <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to know how can i drop any element in specific container like in credit side and debit side.

my demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjayrathod/S4QgX/541/

now i want to drag and drop first three element is in credit side only and remaining elements in debit side.

So how can i do this.
Please help.

Comment: I couldn't understand what's wrong with your fiddle

Comment: You want to be able to drop given element only in a specific container?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my fiddle bro
6 elements in blocks can be drag and drop into crdit side blocks and debit side block.

Comment: no i can drag and drop elements into both side credit side and debit side but i want to drag and drop into specific contaner like first three elements intop credit side and remaining can be drag and drop into debit side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add specific class name in accept parameter of dropable area.
Add the class credit or debit in the dragable element.

```
$("#shoppingCart1 ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept:".credit",  //for credit
    drop: function(event, ui) {


$("#shoppingCart2 ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept:".debit",  //for credit
    drop: function(event, ui) {
```

[DEMO Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/dxLda/)

Comment: Thank you sudhAnsu63. Your demo worked.Thankyou so much i am trying this around three hours

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict dropping elements to specific containers use 'accept' option of target droppable: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#accepted-elements.

It determines elements that can be dropped via selector e.g.

```
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      accept: "#canBeDroppedId",
      ...
 });
```

Comment: Ya i know that bro but can you please do in jfiddle.I have tried this but cannot get success